# "White people" crime?

Tags: united-states, criminology, race

In US popular culture, it's often asserted that white people are more prone to commit certain types of crime that are "crazy", such as serial murder, child abduction, mass shooting, etc. 
This is often portrayed in movies, the most recent example being "Get Out" (which I saw last night):

[Here is a quote from the movie:](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5052448/quotes)

> Or... I don't know if you noticed, white people love making people sex slaves and shit.

Is there any statistically significant evidence to support that

1. White people are more likely to be serial killers or
2. Are most likely to commit child abduction / or have "sex slaves" or
3. Are more likely to commit mass shootings

This does not include terrorism or other mass murder such as organized crime / gang shootings, etc.

Edit: Definitions per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_killer):

> A serial killer is typically a person who murders three or more people, usually in service of abnormal psychological gratification, with the murders taking place over more than a month and including a significant break (a "cooling off period") between them. Serial killing is not the same as mass murdering (killing numerous people in a given incident); nor is it spree killing (in which murders are committed in two or more locations, in a short time). However, cases of extended bouts of sequential killings over periods of weeks or months with no apparent "cooling off period" or "return to normalcy" have caused some experts to suggest a hybrid category of "spree-serial killer".

Comment: This may be a poor question just because 'white' is such a vague concept. Do you include East Europeans, Cameras, Italians, Greeks, North Africans, Arabic people, Hispanics, Native Americans, Brahmin, Arabs, Iranians, Indians, Somalians? Is it just Anglo-Saxons or people of North, West and Central European descent? I'm sure someone could generate some subset of these people that, by chance, commit strange crimes at high rates. Voting to close due to that.

Comment: No, what is asserted is that when a white person commits such a crime, he's called "crazy" or "mentally disturbed" or "a loner", whereas when a black person does something they're "obviously a thug" "probably in a gang" and when a brown person does it they're terrorists.

Comment: I'm also voting to close as duplicate, but the question also seems too broad and unclear; "crazy" crimes is just too vague, and the difference between serial killer / terrorist / gang isn't clear enough here. It would probably help if you could add a better source with a more specific - and notable - claim.

Comment: Mass murder includes every incident where more than N (I think 3) people are killed. For example the st valentine's day massacre. That's obviously a mob hit, very different than something like Columbine where the identity of the victims was not particularly important. So there is a clear difference between the two. Also, I think serial murder is self explanatory

Comment: Ariel Castro kidnappings for example is the type of crimes that I consider valid under category #2. I think that's a very distinct type of crime, not your run of the mill kidnapping.

Comment: Often times people like Ariel Castro, the Zodiac, the perpetrators of Columbine and Sandy Hook, will be described as crazy, mentally deranged individuals, both in the media and popular culture.

Comment: I will note that there is no real correspondence between the OP's categories and the category (only one) in the duplicate.  "Serial killer" is not the same as "mass murderer".

Comment: I disagree with closing it. The 9-11 hijackers are mass murderers but not serial killers. Completely different things, thus not a duplicate question.

Comment: @ventsyv the only claim in the OP is "white people love making people sex slaves and shit", which is not about any kind of killing and is not about "more likely".

Comment: There was nothing about murderers of any sort in the quote.  Also, fictitious movies probably aren't a valid source of claims.  Some of these problems could be addressed by selecting a better source for the claim.

Comment: The issue of duplication's trickier.  It seems like a lot of questions closed as exact duplicates aren't actually exact duplicates, as there's often some minor difference, e.g. the difference between mass murderers and serial murderers.  I don't know if it's intentional or not, but my guess has been that there's intent to avoid having too many closely related questions.

Comment: The are actually two completely different things because of the psychological component.

Comment: It might be a point that could be argued if a good source for the claim could be found.  For example, if a claim really just argues that white people are more likely to commit "creepy" crimes, then it seems unlikely the claimant's really making the distinction between serial and mass murder themselves.  But if there's a notable source that clearly calls out serial murder in specific, where it's obvious that they specifically mean serial murder, then that'd seem to be a much stronger case.